Is it possible to Cross-Compile TensorFlow Lite C API for arm64 bare metal target?
I am writing code that uses the tensorflow lite C API code and that will run on an Arm board targeting bare metal. I am trying to obtain the shared library of tensorflow lite but until now I only see cross compile methods that targets linux. Is it because cross compiling the tensorflow lite library on bare metal is not possible ? Or not done in general?
For instance using bazel they use bazel build --config=elinux_aarch64 -c opt //tensorflow/lite/c:libtensorflowlite_c.so
I tried to figure out how to change the config files to target bare metal and use my aarch64-none-elf toolchain but I could not figure out.
I also tried to make my own cmake toolchain file using my aarch64-none-elf cross compile toolchain however , executing *cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE= ../tensorflow/lite/

fails.

